# Android + Google Analytics: Check if app has crashed

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am currently giving Google Analytics a try and all that keeps me from switching is one important feature:

With Crittercism and other crash reporting services, I have a method like "didCrash()" or something like that. That function returns true if the app has crashed the last time the user used it.

I'm using this to display a help dialog to the user with links to the issue tracker, etc...

But I'm completely missing such a method in the Analytics SDK. Is there such a method?

Is there any elegant way I can implement this manually like using ExceptionReporter or something like that?

Goddchen

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to report App Crashes or uncaught Exceptions to Google Analytics Dashboard:

```
/* Google Analytics Code to track uncaught Excepions */
Tracker m_GaTracker =  m_GaInstance.getTracker("UA-------");
        final UncaughtExceptionHandler myHandler = new ExceptionReporter(m_GaTracker, GAServiceManager.getInstance(),
                Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(), this);
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(myHandler);
```

Comment: Well that's really not what I asked :( sorry